# How can I format a time to appear in a FormattedJTextField in the format hh:mm, with no AM or PM after it?

Tags: java, jformattedtextfield

How can I format a time to appear in a [JFormattedTextField](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFormattedTextField.html) in the format `hh:mm`, with no AM or PM after it and a proceeding 0 in the case of a single digit hour (e.g. "09:30")? Thanks in advance. I have tried using `DateFormat` to do this but it adds on the am/pm.

Comment: Use a `SimpleDateFormat` with a pattern that does not include AM/PM marker.

Comment: You can find here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html date formats without AM/PM

Comment: The 24-hour format would be `HH:mm`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SimpleDateFormat object:

```
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    dateFormat.format(yourDate);
```

In the date format constructor `HH` refers to a two digit hour from 0-23, `mm` refers to minutes.